# How to get post_impression_organic by hour, day or time period?

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a statistic of post_impressions_* by a time frame (hour, day, etc) but all I seem to get is "lifetime"

```
{post_id}/insights/post_impressions_organic/lifetime
```

If I try anything other than lifetime, like week or day, I get nothing, and even if I could get lifetime, not sure how to break it down by day, or hour.

For example:

```
- impressions
-- day 3/25: 100
-- day 3/26: 200 total: 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't. Please check out Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights/

At this document you'll find all different metrics and the period you can use for each one. As you can see, post_impressions_organic* only offers "lifetime" period. You should see "day" or "week" on the period column in order to use a different period.

I hope it helps.